# how to convert excel sheet to data processing using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, data-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPofo.jpg)how to convert this excel to data processing using pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel(r"c:/Users/vpullabh/Desktop/Meraci.Ec-NGIOSD.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `read_excel` convert an excel file to a dataframe.
You want to add `skiprows` to get directly to the table:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"c:/Users/vpullabh/Desktop/Meraci.Ec-NGIOSD.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1", skiprows=19)
```